# Apache Camel: Preventing out of space while writing files

Tags: java, apache, apache-camel

I am creating a queue of files in tomcat folder with Apache Camel to POST a lot of data to a rest service. What if the endpoint is not available for couple days and you run out of diskspace because it keeps making new files? How to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Its too unclear / too broad what you are asking about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Implement custom [Predicate](http://camel.apache.org/predicate.html) to ensure, there is enough usable space before writing file.

Something like this:

```
private static final Predicate IS_ENOUGH_SPACE = exchange -> {
    return new File(Paths.get("").toUri()).getUsableSpace() > 100*1024*1024; // 100MB
};

public void configure() {
    from("timer:simple?period=1000")
        .choice().when(IS_ENOUGH_SPACE)
                .to("file://myStuff")
                .to("log:done")
            .otherwise()
                .to("log:supressed") // do some handling here, maybe pause route for while
            .end();
}
```

Comment: nice solution! Is there a way to create this predicate with xml?

Comment: Nvm, i achieved it by using:  <method ref="isEnoughDiskSpaceExpression" method="matches"/> within <when> block